# I2C linux device driver, running on Petalinux and running on Zedboard

Tags: linux, driver, i2c, bus

I have read the Linux documentation on writing I2C clients (writing-clients) and have used this blog link http://renjucnair.blogspot.in/2012/01/writing-i2c-driver.html and other resources I could find. I am trying to access the device using the SM-Bus interface and accessing the device file using the file operations used for standard character drivers as shown by the third type in the answer to this [I2C device linux driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979129/i2c-device-linux-driver) question. I am trying to communicate with a magnetometer HMC5883l. I have written the following code finally:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>


#define REG_CONF_A 0x00 
#define REG_CONF_B 0x01
#define REG_MODE 0x02
#define REG_FIELD_X_LSB 0x03
#define REG_FIELD_X_MSB 0x04
#define REG_FIELD_Y_LSB 0x05
#define REG_FIELD_Y_MSB 0x06
#define REG_FIELD_Z_LSB 0x07
#define REG_FIELD_Z_MSB 0x08
#define REG_STATUS 0x09
#define REG_ID_A 0x0A
#define REG_ID_B 0x0B
#define REG_ID_C 0x0C

static char c = 's';

static dev_t first;
static struct cdev c_dev; 
static struct class *cl;
static struct i2c_client *client;

static const struct i2c_device_id hmc5883l_id[] = {
    { "hmc5883l", 0 },
    { }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, hmc5883l_id);
 
static const struct of_device_id hmc5883l_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "honeywell,hmc5883l", .data = 0 },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, hmc5883l_of_match);

static struct i2c_driver hmc5883l_driver = {
    .driver = {
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
    .name       = "hmc5883l",
    .of_match_table = hmc5883l_of_match,
    },
    .id_table   = hmc5883l_id
};

static int hmc5883l_open(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: open()\n");
    return 0;
}
static int hmc5883l_release(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: close()\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t hmc5883l_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{

    struct i2c_adapter *my_adap = i2c_get_adapter(0); 
    client = i2c_new_dummy(my_adap, 0x1e);
        
    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: read()\n");
    if (*off == 0) 
    {
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(client, 0x0a, 0);
    c = i2c_smbus_read_byte(client);
    copy_to_user(buf,&c,1); 
    (*off)++;
    return 1;   
    }
    else  
    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations hmc5883l_fops = {
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
    .read       = hmc5883l_read,
    .open       = hmc5883l_open,
    .release    = hmc5883l_release,
};


static int __init hmc5883l_init(void)
{
    int ret;
    struct device *dev_ret;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Namaskar: mmeter driver registered");
    if ((ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 1, "Shweta")) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }
    if (IS_ERR(cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv")))
    {
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return PTR_ERR(cl);
    }
    if (IS_ERR(dev_ret = device_create(cl, NULL, first, NULL, "mynull")))
    {
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return PTR_ERR(dev_ret);
    }

    cdev_init(&c_dev, &hmc5883l_fops); //this is the step of initializing the character driver.
    
    if ((ret = cdev_add(&c_dev, first, 1)) < 0)
    {
        device_destroy(cl, first);
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return ret;
    }
    
    return i2c_add_driver(&hmc5883l_driver);
}

static void __exit hmc5883l_exit(void)
{
    i2c_del_driver(&hmc5883l_driver);
    cdev_del(&c_dev);
    device_destroy(cl, first);
    class_destroy(cl);
    unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Alvida: mmeter driver unregistered");
    
}


module_init(hmc5883l_init);
module_exit(hmc5883l_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Shubham Sharma");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Mmeter Driver");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I have also made the requisite additions in the device tree as below:

```
/dts-v1/;
/include/ "system-conf.dtsi"
/ {
    amba: amba {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
        ranges;
i2c0: i2c@e0004000 {
            compatible = "cdns,i2c-r1p10";
            status = "okay";
            clocks = <&clkc 38>;
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <0 25 4>;
            reg = <0xe0004000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
        
hmc5883l@1e {
        compatible = "honeywell,hmc5883l";
        reg = <0x1e>;
};
};
};

};
```

This code compiles on my laptop and following are the outputs that I get upon running the following commands when the driver is installed on petalinux on the Zedboard.

```
root@I2C:~# i2cdetect -r -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1e -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --



root@I2C:/dev# cat mynull
Driver: open()
i2c i2c-0: Failed to register i2c client dummy at 0x1e (-16)
Driver: read()
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000002
pgd = 5d898000
[00000002] *pgd=1e4aa831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops - BUG: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: ipv6 mmeter_driver(O)
CPU: 1 PID: 982 Comm: cat Tainted: G           O   3.19.0-xilinx #19
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
task: 5e46f180 ti: 5e4f2000 task.ti: 5e4f2000
PC is at i2c_smbus_write_byte_data+0x8/0x3c
LR is at hmc5883l_read+0x48/0xb4 [mmeter_driver]
pc : [<40332068>]    lr : [<3f000078>]    psr: 600d0013
sp : 5e4f3f10  ip : 00000000  fp : 00000001
r10: 00000000  r9 : 5e4f2000  r8 : 4000dee4
r7 : 3ec43c60  r6 : 3f000628  r5 : 3ec43c60  r4 : 5e4f3f88
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 0000000a  r0 : 00000000
Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 18c5387d  Table: 1d89804a  DAC: 00000015
Process cat (pid: 982, stack limit = 0x5e4f2238)
Stack: (0x5e4f3f10 to 0x5e4f4000)
3f00:                                     5e4f2000 00000000 00000001 4004f0cc
3f20: 3f0003c9 5e4f3f44 00000000 4046fa08 3f0003c9 5e4f3f44 5e4f3f88 3f00005c
3f40: 3f0003c9 5ebef000 0000000a 3f000078 3ec43c60 5e65be80 5e4f3f88 400b9fe4
3f60: 5e65be80 3ec43c60 00001000 5e65be80 5e65be80 00001000 3ec43c60 4000dee4
3f80: 5e4f2000 400ba08c 00000000 00000000 00001000 000aba18 00001000 3ec43c60
3fa0: 00000003 4000dd60 000aba18 00001000 00000003 3ec43c60 00001000 01000000
3fc0: 000aba18 00001000 3ec43c60 00000003 00000003 00000001 00000000 00000001
3fe0: 00000000 3ec43c44 00011a68 36e8125c 600d0010 00000003 00000000 00000000
[<40332068>] (i2c_smbus_write_byte_data) from [<3f000078>] (hmc5883l_read+0x48/0xb4 [mmeter_driver])
[<3f000078>] (hmc5883l_read [mmeter_driver]) from [<400b9fe4>] (vfs_read+0x84/0xec)
[<400b9fe4>] (vfs_read) from [<400ba08c>] (SyS_read+0x40/0x80)
[<400ba08c>] (SyS_read) from [<4000dd60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x34)
Code: e28dd03c e49df004 e52de004 e24dd03c (e1d0c0b2) 
---[ end trace 7a4ba311ad6063f0 ]---
Driver: close()
Segmentation fault
```

I am unable to understand the error that I am making. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. : This is my first question here, so if the question is wrong in the way I posted I am sorry and I will provide anymore details.