# I2C read write functions in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

How is the read and write functions in I2C drivers for linux are communicated to linux? In all the drivers for devices on I2C in the linux source, the `file_operations` structure is not used to tell the kernel about the functions. How is the various functionalities communicated to kernel, so they can be called from user space without using `file_operations`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492850/does-i2c-driver-need-to-be-implemented-just-like-any-other-character-device-driv

Comment: Definitively a duplicate, the answer is exactly the same. Also OP is mistaken, there is exactly one client driver using file_ops: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does i2c driver need to be implemented just like any other character device driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492850/does-i2c-driver-need-to-be-implemented-just-like-any-other-character-device-driv)

Comment: @SamProtsenko, That's what I referred to in the first place.

Comment: @0andriy Yeah. And I agree with your comment. That's why I clicked on "close" link under the question, stating the reason. So that comment of mine was actually left automatically. Never intended to steal that from you or something :)

Answer (score -1):

I2C driver in linux support the file operation as well. Because when you start open i2c from your application;

```
snprintf(filename, 19, "/dev/i2c-%d", adapter_nr);
file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
```

It will call to the i2c-dev.c file in linux kernel

```
static int i2cdev_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);

static const struct file_operations i2cdev_fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .llseek         = no_llseek,
    .read           = i2cdev_read,
    .write          = i2cdev_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl = i2cdev_ioctl,
    .open           = i2cdev_open,
    .release        = i2cdev_release,
};
```

But if you want to read and write from the user space without file_operatoin then you can use the kobject in your driver for read and write through sysfs.

For reading from the user space:

```
static ssize_t module_show_status(struct kobject *kobj,struct kobj_attribute *attr,char *buf);
```

For writing from the user space

```
static ssize_t module_store__status(struct kobject *kobj,struct kobj_attribute *attr,const char *buf, size_t count);
```

But before using these APIs you need to create the kboject in your driver.