# How linux driver can delegate functions to another driver (shared hardware)

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, lirc

I'm writing a custom IR transmitter driver for lirc on an embedded board.  The board has a i2c-to-gpio extender ([FXL6408](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FXL6408-1010410.pdf)).

The problem is that only one GPIO pin is needed for my driver (and hence LIRC) and the other pins are needed for use by other applications.  Something like this:

[image: Driver Connections]

I've read LWM, LDD3, and tons of sites about `i2c-slave`, i2c *adaptors, buses*, `pinctrl`, `gpio`, *stacking* etc but its not clear how to do what I want:

`my-driver` needs to control a single pin on the GPIO extender while still allowing other applications to control the other 7 pins via `/dev/i2c-0`.

Following [this SO suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979129/i2c-device-linux-driver) was promising but `i2c_new_dummy` failed, returning NULL:

```
i2cAdaptor = i2c_get_adapter(ECP_I2CBUS); // 1 means i2c-1 bus
if (i2cAdaptor == NULL)
{
    printk("ecp_gpio: Could not acquire i2c adaptor\n");
    return -EBUSY;
}

i2cClient  = i2c_new_dummy(i2cAdaptor, ECP_I2CDEV); // 0x43 - slave address on i2c bus
if (i2cClient == NULL)
{
    printk("ecp_gpio: Could not acquire i2c client\n");
    return -EBUSY;
}

if ( (rc = i2c_smbus_write_byte(i2cClient, 0xF0)) < 0)
{
    printk("ecp_gpio: Error writing byte - error %d", rc);
    return -EIO;
}
```

What is the correct way to hook up the plumbing to achieve what I want?

**OS Info:**

```
# uname -a
Linux ecp 4.4.127-1.el6.elrepo.i686 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 09:44:43 EDT 2018 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: In Linux kernel everything is delegated thru frameworks. In your case there is a driver for GPIO expander, that provides resources to the system thru GPIO library. In the other driver you just call something like `gpiod_get(dev, “pin_name”);`, where name of the pin comes thru device properties (they may be gathered in Device Tree, ACPI, or in GPIO tables or software nodes).

Comment: True. But since the GPIO device is at the end of an i2c bus what my driver must do is communicate over i2c.  Any existing gpio driver will not be aware of the GPIO device, so the task at hand is to control i2c, hence using the i2c framework to control i2c, no?

Comment: No. What you need is to investigate if vanilla kernel has a driver for this expander (or quite similar one which you can modify), or write a new one (plenty examples) and use what I put in the first comment.

Comment: Just in case there is a common library for such chips, called `bgpio` in *drivers/gpio/gpio-mmio.c*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.  Unfortunately, I did some testing on the (down voted) solution using `i2c_smbux_xfer`.  It's too slow.  HW must be using the 100 kHz i2c bus.  So back to to the other approach, "Control USART RTS Pin on Embedded Board".  You commented on that question too.  Any leads there?  I'm stuck...

Comment: With driver I was mistaken. It's not as simple as MMIO one, and here was an attempt to submit a more or less proper one https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/683632/.

Answer (score -1):

After trying many different things, I found one that works.  I don't know if it is "the right way" to do it, but it does work.

Instead of trying to create a dummy client, just call the `i2c_xx` functions directly.  So the code looks like:

```
i2cAdaptor = i2c_get_adapter(ECP_I2CBUS); // 1 means i2c-1 bus etc
if (i2cAdaptor == NULL)
{
    printk("ecp_gpio: Could not acquire i2c adaptor\n");
    return -EBUSY;
}


union i2c_smbus_data data;

data.byte = 0xF0;

if ((rc = i2c_smbus_xfer(ecpHardware.i2cAdaptor, ECP_I2CDEV, 0, I2C_SMBUS_WRITE, 0x05, I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA, &data)) < 0)
{
    printk("ecp_gpio: i2c_smbus_xfer failed: %d\n", rc);
    return -EIO;
}

data.byte = 0xE0;

if ((rc = i2c_smbus_xfer(ecpHardware.i2cAdaptor, ECP_I2CDEV, 0, I2C_SMBUS_WRITE, 0x05, I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA, &data)) < 0)
{
    printk("ecp_gpio: i2c_smbus_xfer failed: %d\n", rc);
    return -EIO;
}
```

Comment: I did, that's what put me on to the i2c framework. See my explanation above on why the gpio framework is not applicable for the use case.  (I suppose that if I wanted to present the device to user space as a GPIO then I would register a gpio driver.  But user space shouldn't know anything at all about the i2c or gpio.  So "my-driver" need only control i2c to do what it needs to do.  Correct?